# Google Maps JavaScript API Autocomplete with Current Location Option

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, geolocation

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API with Autocomplete.

I would like to add an option (that appears as the first menu option before the Google-generated autocomplete options) for the user's current location:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Start: Your Location" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

JS:

```
var map;

function initMap() {

  var input = document.getElementById('address');
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
  });

}

function getCurrentLocation() {

    // Try HTML5 geolocation

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            var location  = new google.maps.LatLng(pos['lat'], pos['lng']);    // turn coordinates into an object

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': location}, function (results, status) {

                if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    // Add option as first option in autocomplete display

                 }

            });

        }, function() {

        });

    } else {

        console.log('could not get your location.');

        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation

    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    }

}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rf9qa47/1/) showing the map and autocomplete.

Comment: every get this to work? I'm trying to do something similar